# Overwriting Null values in an existing column in Big Query table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column in my source table which has a certain amount of null values. I want to replace those null values by "TV" without creating a new column for it. Is there any way using IFNULL() or is there another solution to it?

Tried this solution but it creates a new column. I don't want that

Comment: Hi Mayank - yes, you'd query the table using `IFNULL()` on that column, if you alias it with the same name it won;t create a new table. If this doesn't help, please share some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can `UPDATE` your table:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.full_of_nulls` 
SET c='TV'
WHERE c IS NULL
```